# ¿Saber que checkbox en un ciclo han sido seleccionados?

Tags: javascript, sql, asp

Mi duda es como puedo saber que checkbox han sido seleccionados para actualizar los input de tipo texto que contiene ese checkbox

se ve de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la tabla y el checkbox está dentro de un bucle la cual imprime tantas tablas que la consulta de sql tenga

esto es lo que tengo en codigo

```
<%do while not siresic.EOF inc= inc +1 %>
```

mis inputs de tipo texto están dentro de este ciclo de esta forma, le pongo el valor del incremento para identificarlos cada uno

```
<td style="background-color:#FFFFFF" width="10%"><input onpaste="return false" name="Tipo_acta<%Response.Write (inc)%>" type="text" SIZE="5" height=50 id="Tipo_acta<%Response.Write (inc)%>" value="<%Response.Write siresic.Fields("Tipo_acta").Value%>" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"> </td>
```

y mi checkbox está de esta forma

```
<td style="background-color:#FFFFFF" width="10%" rowspan="3"><input type="checkbox" name="actualizar" value="act<%Response.Write (inc)%>"> </td>
```

Esto es lo que se me a ocurrido para irlos identificando cada uno pero ahora no se como podría saber que checkbox seleccionó el usuario para de ahí actualizar los inputs cabe mencionar que el uno y dos que se ve en mi tabla también es con el incremento.

PD: agradecería mucho cualquier ejemplo aunque no sea con asp solo quiero saber como le podría hacer en este caso

Answer (score 0):

la funcionalidad de tu tabla es que primero modificas alguno de los inputs, seleccionas el checkbox para indicar cual es el que se va a modificar y posteriormente presionas el boton de actualizar?.

De ser así, supongo que en el ciclo que traes de tu BD, para llenar esa tabla, le asignas el idendity de cada campo ya sea al checkbox o al tr como tal.

Lo que podrias hacer es que en el evento click del checkbox (en caso de que el identity este dentro del mismo), asignes ese identity a alguna variable para posteriormente mandarlo en el update y se seleccione solo ese campo de la BD.

Con Jquery haria algo así:

```
$('.table tbody').on('click','#update-btn', function(event){
        var identity = 0;
        identity = $(this).val();  
});
```

El valor identity lo pasas como parametro en el Update.

Espero y te sirva mi humilde opinion, y espero haberte entendido.

Saludos.